# Gradle dependency version syntax

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm new to gradle. I have such a dependecy im my gradle script:

```
compile group: 'com.ning', name: 'async-http-client', version: '[1.6.1,1.9['
```

Could someone explain me, what does this `version: '[1.6.1,1.9['` mean in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Ivy-style versions range, take a look [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/settings/version-matchers.html). In this case, this means, version can be greater or equal to 1.6.1 and lower than 1.9.